# ssh: User not allowed shell does not exist

Tags: linux, git, shell, ssh

- Apache
- CentosOS 5
- Plesk 10

New on commandline and ssh.

While trying to get several users (root git friend) to ssh to the same shell and configuring passwordless connection I must have made a mistake.

I can **no longer login over ssh as root** or git but can as friend whose shell I transferred by editting etc/passwd. 
I luckily can still login on plesk so gui file editing is possible.

here's what I found in my sshd errorlog

```
sshd[11999]: User git not allowed because shell /bin/bash\r does not exist
sshd[12000]: input_userauth_request: invalid user git
sshd[11999]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=xxx.xxx.xxx.dynamic.upc.nl  user=git
sshd[11999]: Failed password for invalid user git from xxx.xxx.xxx port 54851 ssh2
```

I read something about sudo ing and incidently entering: causing the \r
But where to restore?
Here are some configurations

etc/ssh/sshd_config :

```
PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

ect/shells

```
/bin/sh
/bin/bash
/sbin/nologin
/bin/tcsh
/bin/csh
/bin/false
/usr/local/psa/bin/chrootsh
/bin/rbash
```

etc/passwd

```
git:x:10009:10009::/home/git:/bin/bash
friend:x:10010:10010::/home/git:/bin/bash
```

earlier I tried to install password less connecting
so there is a .ssh/id_rsa file somewhere on the server and on my local machine.

After reading [Git's famous "ERROR: Permission to .git denied to user"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335197/gits-famous-error-permission-to-git-denied-to-user)

I tried

```
ssh-add -l
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent
```

My problem resembles this:
https://serverfault.com/questions/480806/ssh-root-access-denied-after-changing-shell

If I am logged over ssh as friend I cannot sudo to root:

```
sudo root 
friend is not in the sudoers file
```

nor can I chsh

```
[friend@vpsXXX ~]$ chsh -s /bin/bash root
chsh: Running UID doesn't match UID of user we're altering, shell change denied
```

Hope someone can clear this up for me.

Happy to supply more info if needed

Answer (score 2):

```
/bin/bash\r
```

means that you've edited the /etc/passwd or /etc/shells with a Windows editor as it contains Windows line feeds `\r\n`. Linux interprets only the `\n` and assumes that the remaining `\r` is part of the binary name.

Solution: Open the files in a Linux editor and remove the new line and add it again.

Also you could install the package `tofrodos` and execute:

```
fromdos /etc/passwd
fromdos /etc/shells
```

Comment: correct, I did it in Plesk, now I try to learn vi quickly and first change the permissions to friend

Comment: vim is the best choise for editing files IMO :) if you need something simpler for the start you can use `nano` or even `mc`

Comment: Strange I tried to remove newlines but there weren't any. :wq  But still the same error: /bin/bash\r

Comment: Hmmm :wq is not correct for saving :x is so I read in the manual. Using vim now. But still the same error. Even after backspacing and entering again on every bin/bash line.

Comment: have you tried `fromdos` ?

Comment: I am bit scared about that. Will those files still be accessible / editable for Linux? Installing with Yum?

Comment: fromdos just removes windows line feeds and turns them into linux line feeds. it is safe to use it

Comment: Ok I will try. I the meantime I cannot ssh with friend no more. So I have to manage with plesk...