# Can't push changes to github

Tags: git, github

I try to push file to `GitHub` but have this error

```
remote: Permission to user_name1/project_name.git denied to user_name2.
fatal: unable to access 'project_https_links': The requested URL returned 
error: 403
```

It means that I have no permission in `project_name` by `user_name2` but I have configured user.name in `global` is `user_name1` which has full permission.

*config*

```
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=input
core.fscache=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
help.format=html
rebase.autosquash=true
http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
credential.helper=manager
user.email=my_email
user.name=user_name1
gc.autodetach=false
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
remote.origin.url=project_https_links
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

So how can I push my changes? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `user.name` property of git is not related to GitHub username in any way.

Comment: @1615903 it is the same, I checked.

Comment: Have you looked into this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335197/gits-famous-error-permission-to-git-denied-to-user ?