# The requested URL returned error: 403 in Github

Tags: git, github, git-bash

**I am getting this error since there are two repositories from two different accounts, How to resolve this !!**

---

1. I cloned one **`project1`** form **`Account-1`** from github
2. I am able to commit and pushed the changes to this **`Account-1`**
3. I cloned one more **`project2`** from a github account but it is
   different from **`account-2`**
4. I am able to clone from **`Account-2`**
5. But I am not able to push to **`account-2`**

**I get the error as follows**:

```
$ git push origin master
remote: Permission to myAccount/simple-demo.git denied to rahulTcs.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/micheal/simple-demo.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Answer (score 1):

### [This answer helped me solve the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40907049/1083093)

If problem is coming on windows then remove the Credentials from the Windows history.

- Go to Credential Manager
- Go to Windows Credentials
- Delete the entries under Generic Credentials
- Try connecting again.This time , it should prompt you for the correct username and password.

[image]
[image]

[Remove credentials from Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381198/remove-credentials-from-git/39608906#39608906)