# How can I push to multiple GitHub accounts from my PC using git? (different repositories)

Tags: git, github

Is it possible to push to different remote repositories in multiple accounts? I have 2 accounts in GitHub and I have 1 repository from each cloned into my PC. I made commits in both repos, and I want to push both separately to its respective remote. For the first repo, when I pushed it to the remote, it asked for the username and password. But later when I tried to push the second repo to its remote repo, it says `permission denied` and it doesn't even ask for any authorization and gives me this error

```
remote: Permission to anasbasheer/anasbasheer.github.io.git denied to an4s911.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/anasbasheer/anasbasheer.github.io.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

After this I tried using SSH keys but it didn't make a difference.

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with this question? (someone downvoted, I'm new here please fix me if there are any mistakes)

Comment: Are you asking if you can push a single local repo to two different GitHub repos that are each owned by different accounts? Or are you asking to push two different local repos to their corresponding `origin` remotes on GitHub that are owned by different accounts?

Comment: Yeah I was talking about pushing two different local repos to their corresponding origin remotes on GitHub owned.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved!**

I made 2 different ssh keys for both the accounts and now each time I want to make a push to a particular account I have to constantly change the ssh key. (at least something is better than nothing)

These are the steps I did:

**1.** I made an ssh key.

```
$ssh-keygen -t rsa -C 'name@email.com'
```

> here I gave `id_rsa` as the file name when prompted

```
$eval $(ssh-agent -s)
$ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

**2.** I copied the key and added new SSH key in my main GitHub account

To copy the key

```
$clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

To add new SSH key in GitHub

Go to GitHub > Drop-down menu in the top right corner > Settings > SSH and GPG keys > New SSH key > paste the key there

**3.** I made another key with the same steps but with the file name as `id_rsa_2`

Now everywhere in the first 2 steps where `id_rsa` is used it should be replaced with `id_rsa_2`

And then I added this key to my second account.

**4.** Now I cloned both repositories to my computer with the SSH link

```
$git clone git@github.com:username/repo-name.git
```

**5.** That's it and now each time I want to push to one of the accounts I have to change the ssh key

To change SSH key

```
$ssh-add ~/.ssh/your-key
```

in my case, `your-key` will be either `id_rsa` or `id_rsa_2`

Hope this helps others.

Comment: No need to switch keys back and forth. you can create a `~/.ssh/config` file with different `Host` entries that point to the same `HostName` each one having a different `IdentityFile`. You can even add the `User` too. So when you clone you can use `git clone githubOne:username/repo-name.git` where `githubOne` matches the `Host` in your `~/.ssh/config` file.

https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/create-ssh-config-file-on-linux-unix/

Answer (score -1):

First you'll need to add the remote repositories to your local one.

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git
git remote add origin2 https://github.com/user/repo2.git
```

Change `origin` and `origin2` to what ever you want.

Then just use the the remote name you want to push the branch:

```
git push  <REMOTENAME> <BRANCHNAME>
git push origin2 master
```

Comment: actually it is not about the branch. These are completely 2 different repos

Comment: Yes, you can push a branch to two completely different repos by using this method.

Comment: Thats not it. I am talking about 2 separate repos.