# permission to XXX.git denied to user

Tags: git, github

I have changed my GitHub id and caused permission to XXX.git denied to user.

I have found solution from this [Git's famous "ERROR: Permission to .git denied to user"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335197/gits-famous-error-permission-to-git-denied-to-user/40907049#40907049) and solve it and push my latest to mygithub repository but if I push through visual studio code terminal there powershell there it till cause Git ERROR:permission to XXX.git denied to user.

Comment: Did you try restarting your device?

Comment: Yes I have try restart