# git insists on another username even with ssh keys

Tags: git, ssh-keys

I've opened a new github account for school, and added my ssh keys to it, but when I try to push my local repository into it, I get:

```
ERROR: Permission to new-username/repo-name.git denied to old-username.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: please paste the command you clone repo.

Comment: Please also share the output of `git remote -v`

Comment: Hi,
Maybe there is a relative issue in here which might help 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335197/gits-famous-error-permission-to-git-denied-to-user

If you have Mac it's maybe bounded to your keyChain 
If from Windows: might be solved through your credential manager

Answer (score 1):

> and added my ssh keys to it

If your remote repository URL is an HTTPS one, no amount of SSH key will help.

Check your `git config credential.helper`: if it is set and, again, if you are using an HTTPS URL, chances are the credential helper has cached your old credentials.
You need to [remove said credentials from the cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69796505/6309).

---

If your URL is indeed an SSH one:

- check `git config -l` for any `insteadOf` directive which might change it to an HTTPS one.
- make sure you key has a default name like `~/.ssh/id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` (assuming an rsa key), in order to that key to be considered.

Try `export GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -Tv'`, then your `git clone`: you will see which key are considered.

Comment: this is git remote -v, it's not an HTTP URL:
`origin  git@github.com:jonathan-sahar-tau/stimuli-presentation-fmri.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:jonathan-sahar-tau/stimuli-presentation-fmri.git (push)`
and the credential.helper is not set

Comment: @JonathanSahar OK. I have updated the answer acordingly.